# Is it correct to call $A^2$ as "the square of the set $A$" and to call $A^n$ as "the set $A$ raised to the $n$th power"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Let $A$ be a set.
The Cartesian product of $A$ by itself is $A^2=A\times A$.

Also the Cartesian product of $A$ by itself for $n$ times is $A^n=A\times \cdots \times A$.

Is it correct to call $A^2$ is the square of the set $A$ and to call $A^n$ as the set $A$ raised to the $n$th power?

Comment: Not usually called the square of a set. Might be called the Cartesian square of the text, but I'm not even sure I've ever heard it called that.

Comment: I think its most common to say $A^n$ is the set of $n$-tuples of $A$

Comment: Wikipedia calls it ‘$n$-ary Cartesian power’

Comment: "square" and "raised to the $n$-the power" are not common terms for Cartesian products. I suggest avoiding this language in written material. If you're giving a talk, you can say at the beginning that you'll use this terminology for convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I have not seen the terminology "square" and would use "second (cartesian) power". The term "(cartesian) power of a set" is used commonly in some fields, in fact in category theory there is a whole concept called a [power](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/powering), which generalizes the operation $X^{I} = X \times ... \times X \;(\#I\text{ times})$ on sets.

The problem with "power of a set" is of cause that it might lead to confusions with the "powerset of a set", but I think this is not a big problem, since in the end $\mathcal{P}(X) = \mathbf{2}^X$.